# Viewing a Question in Safari Causes Numerous Console Errors

Tags: bug, advertising

Creating this post based on request from the Ad Ops team per https://twitter.com/stevvve/status/857114992692350976?cn=cmVwbHk%3D&refsrc=email

When viewing a Stack Overflow question in Safari, there are numerous console errors. The problem does NOT exist in Chrome.

[image: Console errors]

#### Steps to Reproduce

- Open [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) in Safari
- Open the developer tools and
  select the console tab
- Click any of the questions in the list. For
  example:
  *[How to pull information from a CSV file for use in a stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667591/how-to-pull-information-from-a-csv-file-for-use-in-a-stacked-bar-chart)*
- Notice that the console repeatedly errors for `Block a frame with origin ...`

Comment: Hmm.  Ads being blocked.  I assume your Safari isn't running any ad blockers?

Comment: Looks like a protocol mismatch: HTTPS/HTTP. The site is HTTPS, the frame contents are HTTP. It would appear that Safari is requiring all content on an HTTPS page to be HTTPS or rejecting/blocking it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu No add blockers in Safari at all.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio No, Safari doesn't have a built-in ad blocker (but several ad-blocking extensions exist, of course).  These errors would be very unlikely to be caused by an ad blocker anyway; see [Gypsy's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348510/viewing-a-question-in-safari-causes-numerous-console-errors?cb=1#comment469200_348510).

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver: Other way around, actually.

Answer (score 11):

I work in the ad ops team at Stack Overflow. This issue could be caused if you're browsing http://stackoverflow.com but the ads are https. We're actually going to be switching SO completely over to https in the coming weeks, which should resolve the errors you're seeing.